# How to unzip multi-part zip file in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, zip, zsh, unzip

Given [img.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17NPa6h2PrQvcASohpP7CyN9FzFvVg3Xr/view?usp=sharing) which contains 13 copies of the same photo, I need to split the zip file into parts and be able to unzip it from the generated parts. To split it to equal 100KB parts I do:

```
zip img.zip --out img-pt -s 100k
```

which results in

```
100K    img-pt.z01
100K    img-pt.z02
100K    img-pt.z03
 40K    img-pt.zip
```

I am able to extract from the generated parts using [keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) on macOS. However, I am unable to unzip using `unzip`, here's what I try and get:

```
>>> unzip img-pt.zip
Archive:  img-pt.zip
warning [img-pt.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  66
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  26614
file #4:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  49152
file #5:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  73728
file #6:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  3858
file #7:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  30406
file #8:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  49152
file #9:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  81920
file #10:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  7650
file #11:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  34198
file #12:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  57344
file #13:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  81920
 extracting: img/002.jpeg
```

also

```
>>> cat img-pt.z01 img-pt.z02 img-pt.z03 img-pt.zip > img.zip
>>> unzip img.zip
Archive:  img.zip
warning [img.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
warning [img.zip]:  307200 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  307204
  (attempting to re-compensate)
   creating: img/
 extracting: img/001.jpeg            
 extracting: img/007.jpeg            
 extracting: img/011.jpeg            
 extracting: img/010.jpeg            
file #6:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  3858
  (attempting to re-compensate)
file #6:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  3858
file #7:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  337606
file #8:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  360448
file #9:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  385024
file #10:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  314850
file #11:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  341398
file #12:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  360448
file #13:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  393216
 extracting: img/002.jpeg
```

How to extract the files in terminal without getting an error? And without concatenating the parts, preferably

Comment: The program *tells* you to expect errors and warnings because you're doing something it doesn't fully support...

Comment: And yet it supports splitting to multiple parts which I find pretty weird

Comment: See the first paragraph of the BUGS section of [the manpage](http://manpagez.com/man/1/unzip/)

Comment: Looks like i need to use `zip -F` on the concatenated parts until they fix whatever is wrong in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

Put all the files `.z*` and `.zip` into the **same directory** and use the following commands:

```bash
zip -s- img-pt.zip -O combined.zip
unzip combined.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're dealing with huge files, you can use 7zip instead to extract directly without having to combine the parts:

```
7z x img-pt.zip
```

That will start extracting right away.